# Attaching network storage to a Docker container for Gitlab (ssh issue)

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, nfs, docker

I'm in the process of installing [Gitlab on my web server using Docker](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab).

Everything is working like a champ until I try to use my NAS as the storage folder.

I was hoping that this was going to work:

Mount the NFS share using /etc/fstab to a local folder:

```
192.168.1.103:/gitlab   /home/user/gitlab_data   nfs   rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr
```

Run Docker with the following volume connection:

```
sudo docker run -v /home/user/gitlab_data:/home/git/data .....
```

And the application works, until I try to push in to a repo with ssh.

I get: Connection Refused, make sure you have the proper permissions....

To be clear, I don't experience this error if I'm mounting a local folder, so I'm relatively confident this isn't an ssh configuration issue.

I'm under the impression that this volume approach is creating what's functionally a symlink somewhere through the chain, which is expressly forbidden throughout the install files.

My question is:

How can I connect a folder on my NAS to my Gitlab Docker container in such a way that it won't trigger this ssh/symlink failure?

I've searched for documentation for how to connect the drive directly, but nothing has quite done the trick yet.  In no way am I tied to NFS, I just started there because I read somewhere that Docker supports them.

Cheers,
-Berger

Comment: Alright, found a solution.

I was mounting the docker volume with the root folder of the fstab mount, which introduces the error. I created a folder below the fstab mount, attached that as the volume in docker, and everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

usually in linux (file systems actually) a mount cannot be done recursively (with the exception of layered filesystems like unionfs, aufs, etc.).

For example if you do something like:

`mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
ls /mnt`

this will show you the contents of drive at /dev/sdb1 and this is exactly what you were doing. general rule is that you should never mount a device at a location that is already a mount point for some other device.

A docker volume mount (-v) is just a regular linux operation and thats why you would see this issue.